# Convolutional neural network (CNN) on decimal values

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have a lot of csv file containing approximately 1000 rows and 2 columns where the data looks like this:

```
21260.35679 0.008732499 
21282.111   0.008729349
21303.86521 0.008721652
21325.61943 0.008708224
```

These two are the features where the output will be a device name. Each csv file is data from a specific device of different times and there are also many devices. What I am trying to do is train the data and then classify the device name using CNN. If there is any incoming data outside of the trained observation, it should be classified as anomaly.

I am trying to convert those values to image matrix so that I can use CNN to train this data. But I what I am concerned about is, the second columns contains value less than 1 or and close to zero and the value is also float. If I convert it to integer it becomes zero and if all the values becomes zero then it doesn't make any sense.

How to solve this? And is it even possible to use CNN on these datasets?

Comment: Do you want to predict the second column using the first column ? Please, give a better description of the task you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hello, I am sorry, my description wasn't clear enough. I have edited my post, hope it makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, your problem seems to be a sequence classification.

You have many temporal sequences. Each sequence has the same quantity of 2D elements and is associated to a device. Given a sequence as input, you want to predict the corresponding device.

This kind of temporal dependencies are better captured by RNNs. I would suggest giving a look at [LSTM](https://machinelearningmastery.com/sequence-classification-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/) .